# Is there a way to provide feedback to a moderator?

Tags: discussion

We need a method to rank down/up moderators or at least have an ability provide feedback to them.

I have recently been given a rude comment from a moderator (Rahul). To be honest I expect a bit more respectful comments from moderators. This comment is accusatory and speculative.

I have also noticed that a lot of other valid question get closed or moderators tell users "use google to find answers to your question". That is not a "welcome" for anyone and does not promote good user experience. Moderators should be moderated otherwise you will alienate the users of this site. Some moderator also closed a question stating that a good question has only one correct answer which is completely wrong.

For reference, here is the rude comment from Rahul
[Why does new Gmail interface has a compose window at the bottom right corner?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28602/why-does-new-gmail-interface-has-a-compose-window-at-the-bottom-right-corner)

> "I don't like this new feature and want to complain about it so I'll post a rant on UX masked as a question to vent." Good try, but that doesn't work here. What also doesn't work: rewriting the question to ask people how they would redesign it. That's just a contentious, speculative question that doesn't actually help anyone. – Rahul♦ 2 days ago

Comment: Hi Anna, sorry if you felt that was rude, it wasn't intended that way. If you want to talk about it you can visit me in the UX chat room. Again, apologies if my comment came off harshly. :-)

Answer (score 3):

While there is no specific way to provide feedback on moderators there are courses of action you can take if you disagree with the treatment you have received from anyone on the site, moderators included.

To paraphrase [this post on the main Meta stackoverflow site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges):

---

If you have a dispute with a diamond moderator your options are:

- [Contact stackexchange with your complaint](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help) and links to the questions/answers.
- Flag for moderator attention and request a specific moderator to address.
- Post to the site Meta (as you have done here) and ask for a response as to why your post was closed / deleted.

For the record. The levels of moderation on stackexchange are:

- Developers - Jeff and company.
- Diamond Moderators - Selected by community and listed in the About page of each site.
- 10K Moderators - Gained 10k reputation and access to moderation utilities.

---

Regarding your specific query on your question though, [the main FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) *specifically* mentions that questions that are rants disguised as a question are subjective and should not be asked (this FAQ is global for all Stackexchange sites so has not been written by any of the moderators on this site).

The question was closed for this reason. It also may or may not have been flagged for moderator attention so although it is only Rahul whose name is on the closure, if the post was flagged for moderator attention this is anonymous so details of who flagged it (if anyone) would not be made visible.

As for your point that questions are closed if there is no 'correct' answer available for them - this is not strictly true. There does not have to be a *correct* answer, but the question *does* need to be able to be answered. Again [from the FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) "Remember, this a Q&A site, not a discussion board."

As the closure notice describes:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Again, closure notices are not written by moderators, they are global for all stackexchange sites and help reinforce the suitable question format for this group of sites.

Finally, the main subject of your question - that you feel the comment itself was rude and shouldn't have been left. I reviewed that comment personally and was in two minds as to whether it should remain or not, but in the end decided it was a fair comment (if somewhat on the harsh side). In my opinion it was not rude, it just describes the issue he had with your question as well as why he feels it is not appropriate for the site. Not only does that comment provide useful feedback to yourself, it is also informative to other users of the site. For this reason I let the comment stand.

However, comments are not permanent and can be deleted at any time so whether Rahul decides to keep this comment is up to him.

Overall though, I am sorry if you had a bad experience with this question, and you are well within your rights to voice your complaints both here on Meta.UX as well as directly to Stackexchange themselves as detailed above, but I would like to think that you take the comments in the spirit they are meant because we do still want to help you with future UX issues you have, and I hope you can contribute to the site in future and that this issue doesn't push you away from the site.

Comment: One thing that makes no sense to me is how in any way my question is a rant? Rahul's comment is in fact a rant. His comment is NOT useful I any way and it is insulting. As you can tell by my reputation points I am not the 1st time visitor who just wanted to rant. I still strongly believe my question is valid. By keeping his comment you encourage rudeness and discourage site usage. I suppose there is just a general issue how this site is moderated.

Comment: Another thought... A lot of questions are closed due to them being more appropriate for discussion so why not to give users an easy way to move a question to discussion? Let users use the site as they want to use it and shape their behavior by providing controls that provide positive user experience. What the stack exchange designers should see is an opportunity for something new. I believe users will have more positive experience. Currently, user asks a question and then gets negative feedback - "closed" question.

Comment: There is a way to move into discussion already - there is the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) page, as was mentioned in a comment against the question. StackExchange wasn't designed for discussions, the sites have a clear focus - Questions and Answers. *Believe me*, you are *not* alone in wanting to be able to have discussions on various related topics - *all* the Meta sites on the other SE sites will have people requesting the same thing. However the SE engine just doesn't suit discussions, it's built for questions, answers and community voting. That doesn't fit with discussions.